# Xcode – Stuck on "Performing install actions"

Tags: ios, xcode

It started around 6 months ago and happened from time to time. For last 2-3 days I completely lost opportunity to debug on device. Whenever I'm trying it, I get infinite stuck on "Performing install actions" step. Sometimes, it ends with "unknown error occurred", sometimes with "Could not launch", sometimes it just stuck without any error.

I know the problem is in my specific iPhone, because it doesn't happen with another iPhones and it does happen with my iPhone on different machines.

What I've already tried and it sometimes helped me, but now it doesn't help at all:

- restart Xcode
- restart Macbook
- clean build folder/derived data (yeah, I'm an experienced iOS developer, so I've tried that)
- unpair device and pair it once again (I should say, that previously I thought that was a silver bullet)
- reinstall Xcode
- reinstall iOS Device Support
- turn on/turn off Wi-Fi/Bluetooth
- reboot iPhone
- reset iPhone
- reinstall provisioning profiles
- pray
- unpair Apple Watch
- turn off Apple Watch

My setup: Xcode 14.2 (tried different versions too, for example, Xcode 13), iPhone 11 (iOS 16.2, started when I was on iOS 15)

Once again, I don't have any problems when I debug on Simulator on different device.

Any recommendations would be really appreciated, cause I'm already starting to lose my mind.

Comment: May be problem with the cable?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Tried differenct cables, also it works file with a different device.

Comment: Did you find anything to fix this? I am having the same issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue was magically fixed with the release of Xcode 15.